# Jssor Slider Internet explorer issue

Tags: html, css, slider, internet-explorer-11, jssor

Good Morning,

The following website http://mnb-crossmediadesign.de/vorschau/wiewelhove/pellets.php?lang=de has some slider issues on IE 11. (I did not try any versions before this)
It works perfectly fine in chrome and firefox thou.

I have tried different solution examples which I found on the search function like changing the DOCTYPE to

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

or adding the meta

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

but nothing seem to fix my issue.
The weird thing is also. When Im on that page and I press F5 for refresh, it shows everything correctly. As soon as I go back on that page it is messed up again.

Thanks in advance for your solutions.

Updated information: As far as I see it is only messed up on this test version of the website and not on the original see here: http://wiewelhove.de/pellets.php?lang=de  . weird thing, could it be the php version we are using?

Comment: Have you  tried to set `overflow:hidden` to the parent container of the slider?

Comment: I have tried that but it did not change anything in IE11. Still same issue.

Comment: How could it be, that it actually works if i refresh the website via. F5 and then everything looks good until I switch to a new page?!

Comment: What do you mean 'As soon as I go back on that page it is messed up again'?

Comment: I mean when I visit the page, everything looks messed up. As soon as I press F5 to refresh..everything looks OK. until I switch to another page and back, then everything looks bad in Internet explorer 11 again. I will try to take some screenshots.

Comment: You can check it on the album on imgur: http://imgur.com/a/6pcpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following code,

```
//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing
function ScaleSlider() {
    var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
    if (refSize) {
        refSize = Math.min(refSize, 735);
        jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
    }
    else {
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
    }
}
ScaleSlider();
$Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
$Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
$Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
//responsive code end
```

It scales width of slider to `refSize` while window resizing, you can log the refSize to see what's happening.

**Edit**
Please remove the following lines in your style.css.

```
#jssor_1 {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: im not really into javascript. could you explain what you mean by that? its not done by simply echo'ing refSize, right?